# GoogleAuthIOException when enabling authentication in android mobile backend

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I am going through the google app engine's Mobile Backend Starter tutorial (https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/). It works perfect up to the point of enabling push notifications. The last part, enabling authentication, however, is giving me sleepless nights. I have followed this [guide](https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/android/enable_auth) verbatim, but am getting these errors:

```
02-01 00:11:08.497: I/CloudBackend(1982): error: 
02-01 00:11:08.497: I/CloudBackend(1982): com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthIOException
02-01 00:11:08.497: I/CloudBackend(1982):   at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential$RequestHandler.intercept(GoogleAccountCredential.java:308)
02-01 00:11:08.497: I/CloudBackend(1982):   at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:854)
02-01 00:11:08.497: I/CloudBackend(1982):   at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
02-01 00:11:08.497: I/CloudBackend(1982):   at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
02-01 00:11:08.497: I/CloudBackend(1982):   at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
02-01 00:11:08.497: I/CloudBackend(1982):   at com.google.cloud.backend.core.CloudBackend.list(CloudBackend.java:314)
02-01 00:11:08.497: I/CloudBackend(1982):   at com.google.cloud.backend.core.CloudBackendAsync.access$8(CloudBackendAsync.java:1)
02-01 00:11:08.497: I/CloudBackend(1982):   at com.google.cloud.backend.core.CloudBackendAsync$9.callBackend(CloudBackendAsync.java:270)
02-01 00:11:08.497: I/CloudBackend(1982):   at com.google.cloud.backend.core.CloudBackendAsync$9.callBackend(CloudBackendAsync.java:1)
02-01 00:11:08.497: I/CloudBackend(1982):   at com.google.cloud.backend.core.CloudBackendAsync$BackendCaller.run(CloudBackendAsync.java:402)
02-01 00:11:08.497: I/CloudBackend(1982): Caused by: com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown
02-01 00:11:08.497: I/CloudBackend(1982):   at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
02-01 00:11:08.497: I/CloudBackend(1982):   at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
02-01 00:11:08.497: I/CloudBackend(1982):   at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential.getToken(GoogleAccountCredential.java:277)
02-01 00:11:08.497: I/CloudBackend(1982):   at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential$RequestHandler.intercept(GoogleAccountCredential.java:301)
02-01 00:11:08.497: I/CloudBackend(1982):   ... 9 more
```

I have tried redeploying on the cloud, replacing debug.keystore, etc., but the same error reappears.
I am also getting this warning:

```
02-01 00:16:56.569: W/AbstractGoogleClient(3814): Application name is not set. Call Builder#setApplicationName.
```

Also, a code warning:

> The type ExponentialBackOffPolicy is deprecated

for the import:

```
import com.google.api.client.http.ExponentialBackOffPolicy;
```

I am not sure if these are related. Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you.